# DRY string formatting

Tags: c#, string.format, formatexception

What is an elegant way to pull out common formats (e.g. datetime) for string.format into accessible constants?

Ideally I would like to do something like the following, but I get the below error when I try to use this code.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The date is {1:{0}}", format, now));
```

> [System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>     at Program.Main(): line 9

The reasoning behind this is that certain API's require a specific datetime format. I would like to be able to reference a single place to get that format, such that all or none of the calls will work.

I realize that the following will work, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The date is {1:" + format + "}", format, now));
```

Comment: Do you have a limited list of Date formats you need to support?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy for the time being yes, though it would take some time to enumerate all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go an app constant route - a static class that holds your format strings.

```
namespace App.Framework {
    public static class AppConstant {
        public static readonly string DisplayDateShort = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    }
}
```

As far as your example goes, it's kind of flawed; you want to call `ToString()` on your `DateTime` value.

`Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(AppConstant.DisplayDateShort));`

Comment: So you are proposing the following, `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The date is {0}", now.ToString(format)));`, correct?

Comment: I have a `FormatWith` string extension method that I use to cut down on the noise a bit (`"The date is {0}".FormatWith(now.ToString(format))`), but otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the used format strings under [`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Afterwards you can individually try to parse your input data with each value and see which on returns `true` (see: [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
Console.WriteLine (DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns());
```

[image]

Sample code:

```
void Main()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    foreach(var format in DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()){
        DateTime result;
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(now, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)){
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The date is {0}, the format is: {1}", result, format));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, as I was unaware that you could do this. In my particular case, the datetime is in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider pushing the format into an extension method that could be consumed as needed, i.e.:

```
public static class DateExt
{
    public static string FormatAsSomething( this DateTime dt )
    {
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        string result = dt.ToString( format );
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine( "The date is {0}", now.FormatAsSomething() );
```

Whenever the format needs to be updated, simply update the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom format provider for `DateTime` values:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var str = string.Format(new MyDateFormatter(), "The date is {0}", now);

    Console.WriteLine(str);

    MyDateFormatter.DefaultDateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";

    str = string.Format(new MyDateFormatter(), "The date is {0}", now);

    Console.WriteLine(str);
}

public class MyDateFormatter: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public static string DefaultDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // Check whether this is an appropriate callback              
        if (!this.Equals(formatProvider))
            return null;

        var argFormat = "{0:" + (arg is DateTime ? DefaultDateFormat : string.Empty) + "}";

        return string.Format(argFormat, arg);
    }
}
```